# Como totalizar campos no blade usando Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Caros,
eu estou fazendo um `dashboard`, e montei uma tabela no `HTML`, em uma `View` e preciso totalizar algumas colunas, e gostaria de fazer isso direto no `HTML`, porém como estou utilizando `DB::select` eu não consigo usar o comando `SUM`.

- Será que existe alguma outra forma?
- Será que consigo somar dentro do `HTML`, usando algum comando?

Comment: Coloque seu código? por favor! A `View` e o `Controller` responsável!

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel?

Comment: Você pode usar variáveis para fazer  soma dos valores

Comment: Variáveis no próprio html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Laravel o objeto retornado na consulta é o `Collection`. O mesmo tem um método chamado `sum`, que você pode usar para somar campos específicos (só que a soma é baseada nos resultados carregados pelo PHP, e não no que está no banco).

```
$produtos = DB::table('produtos')->select('quantidade', 'preco')->get();

$total_produtos = $produtos->sum('quantidade');

$total_preco = $produtos->sum('preco');

return view('minha_view', compact('total_produtos', 'total_preco');
```

Comment: Eu fiz os totais e joguei em variaveis, mas como eu tenho que exibir o total de colunas diferentes, de acordo com o módulo, eu acabei fazendo totais de todas as colunas. Mas eu queria que tivesse algo que pudesse usar direto no .blade para totalizar a coluna.
Se alguém tiver outra solução agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esse problema você pode colocar o retorno da sua query em uma variável e passar para a view o total de itens dessa variável. ficaria algo como:

Controller

```
$dados = DB::select('sua query'); 
$total = $dados->count();
return view('nome da sua view')
```

Na sua view você pode pegar o valor total dessa maneira:

```
<div> {{$total}} </div>
```